# Why my question is spammed and downvoted?

Tags: support, downvotes, spam

I asked a question about installing `glucose-syrup` in Ubuntu. Despite all my efforts, I could not get it installed. I was wondering if somebody has success with the installation and could ask for steps.

The deleted post is in: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32542942/4131835.

The question was downvoted, considered spammed and 100 rep was deducted.

Comment: It wasn't spam, but not a great question either...

Comment: What an unfortunately named library.

Comment: @Oded: Whoever named it apparently has a very sweet tooth.

Comment: That's not a good question for SO or anywhere else on SE. If you're having problems installing something, *describe the problems*, error messages, wrong behavior, etc. SO's not the place to get someone to do remote support and talk you through the process of debugging it. Give a specific problem statement so that someone can give you a specific answer.

Comment: Even remote support would need detailed error descriptions, otherwise how can somebody help you?

Comment: Why not posting on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) which is also part of the SE? There installation question are absolutely normal but you need of course to have tried something on your own before. Show some effort and on askubuntu you'll get the help.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like I misclicked when handling a spam flag on the question.

I'll clear the flag, but please take more care when asking questions.

(Looks like I was beaten to it by another mod).

Comment: I did the honors. For posterity, clearing spam flags causes the deletion to be reversed, the automatic downvotes to be removed *and* the deducted rep to be reimbursed. In short, it's as though the post was never spam-flagged in the first place.